# MySQL expression to retrieve percentage

Tags: mysql

I have a table (Table1) with 3 columns:

**Name | RegDate | Active**

I want to know what are the percentages of the rows that are active (**Active=1**) between two dates in **RegDate** column.

For example:
Between '**2013-01-01**' and '**2013-03-31**' (**RegDate** field) I want to know what are the active percentage (**Active=1**)?

It is possible to do this in a single MySQL expression?

At the moment I have this:

> $sql = "SELECT * FROM Table1 t WHERE t.RegDate <= '2013-03-31' AND t.RegDate >= '2013-01-01'";
>
> $sql_executa = $conn->prepare($sql) or die ($sql);
>
> $sql_executa->execute();
>
> $total = $sql_executa->rowCount();
>
> $sql_2 = "SELECT * FROM Table1 t WHERE t.RegDate <= '2013-03-31' AND t.RegDate >= '2013-01-01' AND Active = 1";
>
> $sql_executa_2 = $conn->prepare($sql_2) or die ($sql_2);
>
> $sql_executa_2->execute();
>
> $total_2 = $sql_executa_2->rowCount();
>
> $Percentagem = ($total_2 * 100) / $total;  // This is the answer I need!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT sum( case when Active=1 then 1 else 0 end )
       /
       count(*) 
       * 100  
       As Percent_of_Active_records
FROM Table1 t 
WHERE t.RegDate <= '2013-03-31' 
  AND t.RegDate >= '2013-01-01'
```